# apache commons lang StrTokenizer

Tags: string, apache-commons, tokenize

Since I need empty tokens to read either as empty string or null, I decided to use the apache commons lang `StrTokenizer`
But I am still not able to get the empty string. I know I need to set the `setEmptyTokenAsNull` method before I tokenize. But how can I do that? Please help.

```
tok = new StrTokenizer(line,","); 
tok.setEmptyTokenAsNull(true);
```

Comment: Got it!! Used  tok.setIgnoreEmptyTokens(false); instead!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it!! Used `tok.setIgnoreEmptyTokens(false);` instead!!